# SSRS Parameter with an Either Or condition

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to implement a parameter in SSRS with a condition of an Either OR.  In otherwords, my Branch parameter should be able to search or lookup any branch or multiple branches, or leave it NULL or blank.  Likewise, my RepCode parameter should be able to search or lookup any repcode or multiple repcodes, or leave it NULL or blank.

Currently, I have the branch setup as a required and the repcode setup as a wildcard search

[image]

I've tried using the 'Allow Multiple Values', but can't get it to work correctly without requiring values to be entered.  I would like to be able to enter value in the branch parameter or leave blank and instead enter values in the repcode parameter and return the data.  Do I need `branch in (@branch) and repcode in (@repcode)` to make this work?

[image]

If I leave the branch or repcode blank I get the following error.

[image]

The business user wants the ability to enter a repcode and leave the branch blank, or enter a branch and leave the repcode blank, and be able to enter multiple values in both parameters at will.

Is there a way to do this within SSRS?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Make these parameters nullable in SSRS

In your SQL query use this pattern

```
WHERE (branch in (@branch) and (@branch is not null and @repcode is null))
  OR (repcode in (@repcode) and (@repcode is not null and @branch is null))
  OR (branch in (@repcode) and repcode in (@repcode) and (@branch is not null and @repcode is not null))
```